# Make it easy for team members to chat with each other

Tags: feature-request, chat, old-teams

One complaint that many Stack Overflow users have in common is **it's hard to contact other users**.

Because of the way chat accounts work, you can only find a user's chat profile *if you're already in a chat room with them*. Currently that's the only way you can invite someone to chat with you (either that or you create a room and copy the room URL).

It would be nice to see some form of chat integration with Teams. Even if it's just something as simple as offering a button on teammate's profiles to "invite to room".

Comment: *you can only find a user's chat profile if you're already in a chat room with them* You could use [the chat users page](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users) search (as long as they've ever logged into chat to create an account).

Comment: @JeremyBanks Good tip, I actually wasn't aware of that. Still, it would be nice to be able to invite someone to chat with you even if they haven't created a chat account. There needs to be some form of communication in teams.

Comment: like... a team chatroom.

Comment: @KevinB Perhaps, but keep in mind there are a few rooms where members have been visiting every day for years. They won't want to migrate to a new room. If we were to add a team chatroom feature, there would have to be a way of connecting an existing one.

Comment: I would love the ability to use Stack chat in place of something like Slack, but the team understandably seems to have felt that supporting private chat is off-missing.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Yeah, chat has long been ignored by the SO team

Comment: If your team would want a team chat room, just create a room and link to it from the description or something. Also, since most teams usually exist *outside* of SO, there are probably already some means of communication in place, so adding a general feature like this would just be redundant.

Comment: @poke That's what we currently do in [Lounge<C++>](http://stackoverflow.com/teams/102/loungec) and [JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/teams/57/javascript)

Comment: Chat isn't receiving enough investment from the SO devs to be everyone's IRC or Slack replacement.

Comment: Well, I'm not even looking for a Slack replacement.  I would just appreciate it if we could polish the current chat functionality, and maybe add a couple (minor) features to allow tighter integration with teams or just the ability to chat with other SO users in general. SO chat was never meant to be something like Slack and I certainly don't expect it to be.

Answer (score 6):

I think a new chat room can be created when the team is formed, like it's done with the sites; additionally the tags of the room are taken from the corresponding team's ones. (Then Community posts a welcome message, citing the and description and giving chat faq link, like, again, with the new SE site).

As it's possible for a team to have a chatroom already, then a checkbox to creata a room should be added to the team creation dialog.

On the "cant find a profile" thing: on SO and MSE to get to the chat user profile link, just prepend `chat.` to the profile URL.

Comment: We did think about this. We haven't really decided one way or another, though in the meantime any Team can of course add a link to their chatroom in their description. If we're going to use chat with Teams, we'd consider tighter integration, such as indicating whether members of the Team are currently active in the chatroom, etc.